# How to update the version of AngularJS using module configuration

Tags: 7

I'm trying to build an application using Drupal and AngualarJS. When I download and enable the drupal-angualar module(https://www.drupal.org/project/angularjs) it shows the top version as 1.3.4, but I want to use the latest angular version(1.5.8).

How can I update the angualar version to latest?

Comment: There is no easy way and you have to patch the module or write your one.

Comment: Thank you, the change I have done is mentioned as answer.

Comment: Glad to know that you solved it :D

Answer (score 1):

As @Jimmy Ko suggested I have fixed the issue as follows:

I have added the following code in the function `angularjs_version_files()` of file `sites\all\modules\angularjs\angularjs.module`. Then selected the AngularJS version 1.5.8 in `admin/config/development/angularjs`.

```
$files['1.5.8'] = array(
    'angular-animate',
    'angular-aria',
    'angular-cookies',
    'angular-loader',
    'angular-messages',
    'angular-mocks',
    'angular-resource',
    'angular-route',
    'angular-sanitize',
    'angular-scenario',
    'angular-touch'
  );
```

Now, in the view source I can see the latest AngularJS file is included in my project.